# Welche Wortart ist »genug«?

Tags: adjective, adverb, word-classes

Welche Wortart ist *genug?*

- Der Duden sagt, es sei eine Partikel oder ein Indefinitpronomen.
- Wiktionary sagt, es sei ein nicht deklinierbares Adjektiv.
- Pons (De–En) sagt, es sei ein Adverb.
- DWDS sagt, es ähnele einem Indefinitpronomen und einem Adverb, sei aber eingefrorenes Adjektiv.

Also welche Wortart ist es denn nun?

Comment: Gute Frage. Ich hätte spontan "Adverb" gesagt, aber Deine Quellen und die Ausarbeitung meiner Antwort haben mich vom Gegenteil überzeugt. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eigentlich sind sich beide Quellen ja einig, dass es sich um ein Adjektiv handelt.

Dass Adjektive auch mal als Adverb auftreten, ist ja nicht ungewöhnlich:

> ein **schnelles** Auto
>
> Das Auto fährt **schnell**.

Grundsätzlich haben Adjektive zwei Anwendungsformen: attributiv und prädikativ. Im attributiven Gebrauch wird es flektiert:

> ein **großer** Junge

Im prädikativen Gebrauch behält es im Deutschen seine Wörterbuchform:

> Der Junge **ist groß**.

*Genug* wird bekanntermaßen nicht flektiert, und es tritt auch nicht attributiv auf. Folgendes ist also falsch:

> *eine **genuge** Menge

Prädikativ hingegen kann *genug* als Adjektiv verwendet werden:

> Ein Liter **ist genug**.

Die Verwendung als Adverb ist auch möglich:

> Ich habe heute **genug** gearbeitet.

---

Fazit:
*Genug* ist ein Adjektiv, das nicht flektiert werden kann, aber in prädikativem und adverbialem Gebrauch benutzt wird, wo keine Flexion nötig ist.

Answer (score 2):

Wie Elena schön ausgearbeitet hat, kann *genug* sowohl ein **rein prädikatives Adjektiv** wie auch ein **Adverb** sein. Der Liste möchte ich allerdings noch das **unbestimmte Zahlwort** (**indefinites Numerale**) hinzufügen:

Im Beispielsatz

> Ich habe **genug** Wasser.

ist *genug* als Mengenangabe zu verstehen. Analoge Sätze können lauten:

> Ich habe **wenig** Wasser.
>   Ich habe **ein bisschen** Wasser.
>   Ich habe **kein** Wasser.

Die Verwendung ist nicht auf unzählbare Substantive beschränkt:

> Ich habe **genug** Gänge gegessen.
>   Ich habe **zwei** Gänge gegessen.

und in diesem Beispiel erkennt man auch die direkte Analogie zu bestimmten Zahlwörtern besser.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn in dem Satz

> Ich glaube, dass Peter groß genug ist

"genug" ein Adverb zwischen Adjektiv und Verb ist, was für ein Adverb-Typ ist es dann (Art und Weise?). Problematisch für die Annahme genug=Adverb ist, dass Adverbien im Nebensatz nicht zwischen Adjektiv und Verb stehen können

> Ich glaube, dass (wieder) Peter (wieder) heute (wieder) krank (*wieder) ist

genug aber schon (siehe (ii)). Und auch dass man "genug" nicht an den Satzanfang stellen wie andere Adverbien (i) oder im Satz an eine andere Position (ii):

> (i) *Genug ist Peter groß.
> *Genug hat Peter gespielt. (vs. Schön/Oft hat Peter gespielt)
>
> (ii) *Ich glaube, dass (*genug) Peter (*genug) groß (genug) ist. (vs. dass (schön/oft) Peter (schön/oft) am Strand (schön/oft) gespielt (*schön/oft) hat)

Deshalb ist die Annahme, dass "genug" ein Adverb sein kann, unbefriedigend.

Wenn "genug" ein Adjektiv sein kann, dann fragt man sich, warum es nicht modifiziert werden kann wie andere Adjektive z.B. sehr voll vs. *sehr genug. Es muss außerdem die Beziehung zu dem deklinierbaren Adjektiv "genügend" geklärt werden. Solange alle diese Probleme offen sind, hat man noch lange nicht genug zu "genug" gesagt.

Comment: In diesem Fall handelt es sich bei ["genug" um einen Partikel](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/genug_sehr_recht_ausreichend). Da ist kein Herumraten notwendig.

Answer (score 0):

Das ist genug. - Hier ist genug ein prädikatives Adjektiv mit der Besonderheit, dass es nur prädikativ gebraucht werden kann.

groß genug - genug kann als Adverb nach einem Adjektiv stehen.

genug geredet - Adverb bei Verben.

Also Ajektiv mit eingeschränktem Gebrauch und Adverb wäre als Wortart richtig.