# Vor- und Nachstellung von „genug“

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den vor- und nachgestellten Versionen von *genug*:

> 1. Er hat Geld/Zeit/… genug.
> 2. Er hat genug Geld/Zeit/…

Kann jemand sich ein Beispiel zusammenreimen, bei dem die unterschiedliche Reihenfolge einen Unterschied macht?

**Und wie sieht es mit Adjektiven aus?**

> A. Er ist reich genug.
>   B. Er ist genug reich.

*B.* Kommt mir irgendiwe ungrammatisch vor, stimmt das?

Comment: Stell's davor *und* dahinter: "Genug ist genug"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wie schon in vielen anderen Antworten behandelt, kann die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder innerhalb eines deutschen Satzes relativ frei gewählt werden. Komplett frei ist man in der Wahl der Reihenfolge meist nicht, aber deutlich freier als z.B. in Englisch oder in vielen anderen Sprachen.

Mit der Abweichung von der üblichen Reihenfolge stellt man immer mindestens ein Satzglied an eine ungewöhnliche Position und lenkt damit die Aufmerksamkeit des Leser oder Zuhörers darauf. Es handelt sich dabei also um eine Hervorhebung, also um ein semantisches Stilmittel.

Die übliche Reihenfolge des ersten Beispiels wäre (eingebettet in einen passenden Kontext):

> Er hat genug Geld. Immerhin hat er 40 Jahre lang in einem gut bezahlten Job gearbeitet.
>   Er hat genug Zeit. Jetzt in der Pension plagen ihn keine Termine mehr.

Durch die Vertauschung von Adjektiv und Nomen werden beide hervorgehoben. Es wird also nicht mehr eine einfache Tatsache beschrieben, sondern der Satz lässt sich jetzt eher als Appell verstehen:

> Er hat Geld genug. Soll er doch selber etwas spenden, statt uns dazu aufzufordern.
>   Er hat Zeit genug. Warum macht er das nicht selbst? Warum müssen das andere Leute für ihn machen?

---

**Zur zweiten Frage:**

In B müsste es besser heißen:

> Er ist **genügend** reich.
>   oder
>   Er ist **ausreichend** reich.

Der Satz

> Er ist **genug** reich.

ist formal zwar grammatisch korrekt, aber stilistisch sehr bedenklich.

Answer (score 3):

Schaut man sich die beiden Beispielsätze an, stellt man fest, dass „genug“ hier für zwei vollkommen verschiedene Zwecke eingesetzt wird:

> Er hat genug Geld

Hier beschreibt „genug“ das Nomen „Geld“ näher, ist aber kein Adjektiv. Es steht hier in der gleichen Verwendung wie „kein“, „viel“ oder „wenig“ – Wikipedia nennt das „Indefinitpronomina im weiteren Sinne“ (was immer das heißen soll, auf jeden Fall ein Pronomen, das zum Substantiv gehört).

> Er ist reich genug

Hier handelt es sich bei „genug“ definitiv um kein Pronomen, weil es in dieser Verwendung gar nicht zum Nomen gehört, sondern das Adjektiv „reich“ näher quantifiziert (in ähnlicher Form könnten „kaum“ oder „sehr“ verwendet werden, allerdings mit anderer Satzstellung).

Laut Duden gibt es zwei *genug*, damit handelt es sich eigentlich um zwei verschiedene Wörter:

1. Eine nachgestellte *Partikel* (genauer, eine „Intensitätspartikel“), die einen bestimmten Grad der Eigenschaft (nämlich „genügend davon“) angibt.

   > Er ist reich genug
2. Ein *Pronomen*, das als solches, wie der Name schon sagt, vor das bzw. zum Nomen gehört (das bedeutungsgleiche „genügend“ ist lt. Duden genauso ein Pronomen).

   > Er hat genug Geld

Aus diesem Grund ist *genug reich* nicht grammatisch korrekt, weil *genug* hier verwendet werden soll wie ein Pronomen, aber gar nicht zum Nomen gehört, sondern zu einem Adjektiv.

Erstaunlicherweise funktioniert die Voranstellung **und** Nachstellung der Partikel in einem Satz mit Partizip wie

> Er ist genug gestraft / Er ist gestraft genug

ganz gut. Warum das *da* so ist, habe ich bisher leider noch nicht herausgefunden. Möglicherweise betrachtet man diesen Satz als Idiom, das nicht unbedingt den Regeln folgen muss, oder „genug“ im Fall, dass es vorangestellt wird, als adverbiale Verwendung.

[Außer dort, wo ich explizit meine eigene Ansicht oder Spekulation geäußert habe, steht das alles so im Duden. Ich habe auch andere Grammatiken angeschaut, die hatten jedoch bei Weitem keine so schlüssige Erklärung. Ob man mit dem Statement „genug ist ein Pronomen“ einig (hier sind sich zumindest der Duden und Wikipedia einig) ist, sei dahingestellt. Außer dem sehr offensichtlich unpassenden Nomen und Verb kann man für die Wortart in anderen Quellen praktisch alles finden: „Adjektiv“ (dict.cc), „Adverb“ (canoo.net), „Adjektiv, Präposition oder Postposition“ und wenigstens „Wortart ist strittig“ (Wiktionary) – dann bin ich lieber für Pronomen und Partikel und schließe mich hier dem Duden an. Siehe dazu auch: [Welche Wortart ist »genug«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/welche-wortart-ist-genug) – dort wurde man sich auch nicht einig.]

Comment: Ein Pronomen wird überlicherweise als Ersatz eines Substantivs (= Nomens) benutzt. **Es** steht anstelle des Substantives, das es ersetzt. Welches Wort soll *genug* als Pronomen ersetzen?

Comment: @Jan Nein, nicht notwendigerweise. Es darf das Substantiv auch *ergänzen* - "sein Auto", "Ihr Schreiben vom" und "kein Geld" - *sein*, *ihr* und auch *kein* sind sehr wohl Pronomen.

Comment: *Kein* ist kein Pronomen sondern ein Artikel. *Sein* ersetzt zum Beispiel *Thomas’* und *Ihr* ersetzt zum Beispiel *Herrn Mayrs*.

Comment: Hmm. Ich war auch zuerst deiner Meinung (Pronomen *ersetzt* Nomen), habe mich aber vom Grammatikbuch eines Besseren belehren lassen. Artikel sind "der/die/das/" und "einer/eine/ein[es]". Sonst nix. "Kein" ist genau wie "genug" laut Duden ein Pronomen. Wikipedia sagt allerdings auch " In der modernen Linguistik dagegen versteht man unter Pronomen stets Ausdrücke, die alleine ohne ein Nomen stehen" - Duden scheint also nicht "modern" zu sein.

Comment: Wenn das stimmt hat sich Dudens Grammatik für mich soeben disqualifiziert. *Kein* kann tatsächlich als Pronomen Benutzt werden, allerdings nur in Formen wie »Wir haben *keines*«. Im Fall von *kein Geld* ist es ein Quantifizierer (genau wie *genug*), also eine Art Zahlwort, das sich aber mehr wie ein Artikel als wie ein typisches Zahlwort verhält.

Comment: Canoo scheint "moderner" zu sein - Da steht "Artikel im weiteren Sinne:
Neben den Artikeln im engeren Sinne gibt es weitere Wörter, die die Merkmale eines Artikels aufweisen. Es handelt sich um gewisse Pronomen, die nicht nur allein stehend, sondern auch wie ein Artikel vor einem Nomen verwendet werden. Zu diesen Artikeln im weiteren Sinne gehören zum Beispiel dieser, jener, mein, jeder, kein usw." - Legt sich also nicht fest. Ist das besser? Zu *genug* sagt Canoo, es sei ein *Adverb* (nur das) - Das ist mir zu karg - *Genug Geld* und *reich genug* ist mMn sicher kein Adverb (da kein Verb da)

Comment: Canoo (und gewiss auch einige andere) scheinen immer wieder zu vergessen, dass Adverbe und Adjektive zwei verschiedene Sachen sind, und benützen den ersten Begriff für beides.

Comment: Manchmal habe ich ich eher das Gefühl, das geht nach dem Schema: "Alles, was woanders nicht richtig reinpasst, muss ein Adverb sein."