# Is it strange that genug is not plural?

Tags: pronoun, indefinite-pronoun

> That would occur long before enough could go wrong.

> Das würde passieren, lange bevor **genug** schiefgehen **könnte**.

> That would occur long before enough things could go wrong.

> Das würde passieren, lange bevor **genug** Dinge schiefgehen **könnten**.

You would not say, "That would occur long before enough thing would go wrong." So why is genug not plural? Or is the valence optional in German as it is in English? See [these examples](https://www.dwds.de/r/?from=wb&q=genug%20Ding&h=1&corpus=kern).

Comment: It is the same in English: _it is enough_. Similar: _this is too much_ - _das ist zu viel_

Comment: Where is the latter plural? It differs in mood (can (probably) / could (probably not)) but not in the distinction plural/singular: He can have enough to eat / He could have enough to eat. Both is singular, the latter makes it unlikely (in the speakers opinion)

Comment: OK. I stand corrected. Still, "Enough is there. Enough things are there." Singular and plural.

Comment: Genug ist vorhanden. Genügend Dinge sind hier. (I'm unsure whether 'Genug' could be used here correctly... might at least in everyday speach)

Comment: Yes, but, "Enough is here." or "Enough are here." It is optional in English, depending upon how the speaker wishes to phrase it. And in German?

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/welche-wortart-ist-genug

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately, the question of the valence of genug is not addressed.

Comment: I started an answer but then I decided there were too many uncertainties in the question. First, I'm not sure what you mean by "valence". In linguistics this term is normally applied to verbs and refers to the number and type of arguments (subject and objects) a verb requires. Whether the arguments themselves are singular or plural is usually not a consideration. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)) for more information. ...

Comment: ... Second, with nearly all your examples you're using *genug* as a determiner. Whether a noun phrase is singular or plural depends on the noun, not on the determiner. In your examples, *Dinge* is a plural noun so the verb is plural with *genug Dinge*. With a singular noun, e.g. *Nahrung*, the verb is singular with *genug Nahrung*. ...

Comment: ... Third, I don't agree that using "Enough is here" or "Enough are here" is optional in English. In this case "enough" is pronoun, and if the pronoun refers to a singular noun then the verb is singular and if the pronoun refers to a plural noun then the verb is plural. So if you're talking about things then only "Enough are here" is correct, but it you're talking about food then only "Enough is here" is correct. I don't really know what the rule in in German, but I'd be surprised if it's different. Perhaps you could rephrase the question to focus on that particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in English, you can use "genug" with or without a noun, i.e. you can use it as an adjective or as an indefinite pronoun. I guess that's what you mean by "the valence is optional".

#### Use as an adjective (with reference to a noun)

You can use *genug* to nearer determine a noun like you would use any adjective. *Genug* is not what you would call a normal adjective though.

It isn't declined, which you can justifiably call strange. The reasons lie probably both in its etymology and special meaning. In singular, it behaves more similar to words like "ein bisschen" or  "wenig". In plural, its grammar resembles numerals like "zwei" or "hundert". It's just *genug* in all cases, and both in singular and plural. It can't be increased (no <s>"genüger"</s> or <s>"am genügsten"</s>), there's also no <s>"sehr genug"</s> or <s>"wenig genug"</s>.

> Ist noch genug kaltes Bier da? (nominative singular) *(Is there still enough cold beer?)*

> Sind alle mit genug kaltem Bier versorgt? (dative singular) *(Is everyone supplied with enough cold beer?)*

> Wir haben nicht mehr genug Eier für Pfannkuchen. (accusative plural) *(We don't have enough eggs left to make pancakes.)*

#### Use as an indefinite pronoun

You can use "genug" as an indefinite pronoun. In that case, *genug* replaces a noun.

> Genug ist schiefgegangen. Wir müssen etwas ändern. *(Enough has gone wrong. We'll have to change something.)*

*Genug* is the subject in this sentence. The answer to the question "enough of what?" is only implied. Note that it is only written with a capital letter because it's the beginning of the sentence here. Like all pronouns, it is written in lowercase in the middle of a sentence.

"Genug" as a pronoun is almost always used as a singular. That's why the singular verb form *ist* is used. You could say that something uncountable (think "stuff") is implied. Other words that can be used in a similar way are "etwas", "viel", "wenig" etc.

There are instances where "genug" is clearly refering to something countable, for example persons. In that case you might see a sentence like:

> Ich glaube, es sind genug da, wir können mit der Besprechung anfangen. *(I guess enough are here, we can start the meeting.)*

Unless the implied noun has been mentionend before, this is quite colloquial/sloppy though in German. More correctly, you would always say "genug Leute", "genug Kollegen" or something like that.

If the implied noun has been mentionend before, it's just adjective use with an omission to avoid repetition, which is more common:

> Kann ich mir noch eine Wurst nehmen? - Natürlich, es sind mehr als genug [*omitted:* Würste] da. *(May I help myself to another sausage? - Of course, there are more than enough available.)*

#### Other uses

There are other uses of "genug", for example as an adverb. For more discussion on that, see the answers to this question:

[Welche Wortart ist »genug«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/welche-wortart-ist-genug)